# swiper.js is redirecting my lightbox to the original media URL

Tags: wordpress, image, lightbox, swiper.js

The swiper.min.js file that was part of my WordPress them is not allowing any lightbox related plugins on my website to load. When you click on it, you can see the lightbox arrows for a split second, then it redirects to the original media URL. Can someone pinpoint what it is in the swiper.js file that is making this happen. That way I can remove it. I would so appreciate it. I've been spending days trying to figure out what the issue is, and I've finally at least pin pointed that it's coming from swiper.min.js.

Website link where lightbox plugin is used: https://smithspecialized.com/edmonton-drawworks/

I tried removing some things in the file that I thought had something to do with the lightbox redirecting to media URL, but then it broke the code so I think I removed too much, or the incorrect section in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there it's difficult to find any error without accessing website from inside. If don't want to give access then-

1. please use different plugin or
2. try to disable and enable plugin, as sometime confliction between plugin caused the issue.